# Laravel 9 Breeze with fortify how disable default routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify, laravel-breeze

I use laravel only as a backend for a mobile application, for this I use `Laravel Sanctum` api. I don’t need everything that is displayed in the browser on the site, so I want to disable all unnecessary routes for web. Some of the routes are quite simply removed from the file `app/config/fortify.php`. But there are a few routes that I don't need, such as `login`, `logout` or `_ignition/execute-solution`. Where they are located and how to disable them is not clear.

List of routes that fortify added and that I would like to disable.

```
  POST       _ignition/execute-solution
  GET|HEAD   _ignition/health-check
  POST       _ignition/update-config
  GET|HEAD   livewire/livewire.js
  GET|HEAD   livewire/livewire.js.map 
  POST       livewire/message/{name}
  GET|HEAD   livewire/preview-file/{filename}
  POST       livewire/upload-file
  POST       login
  POST       logout
  POST       user/confirm-password
  GET|HEAD   user/confirmed-password-status
  GET|HEAD   user/profile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable Fortify routes in your Laravel application, you can utilize the `Fortify::ignoreRoutes()` method. This method allows you to remove all Fortify routes.

Open FortifyServiceProvider.php and add this line `Fortify::ignoreRoutes()` to register method, your new code will look like this:

```
public function register(): void
{
    Fortify::ignoreRoutes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove package like as:

```
composer remove facade/ignition
composer remove livewire/livewire
```

Comment: This completely removes the packages, not only the routes. I came looking for the same help and this doesn't address it. Any ideas for specifically disabling certain vendor routes?